# Convertir código de python a java

Tags: java, python

He intentado convertir este código python a java, pero me da erores con las listas.
Quizá no lo he traducido bien.

PYTHON

```
def eligeNodo(valors, ferom, visitados, soluciones):
    #Se calcula la tabla de pesos de cada ciudad
    listaValores  = []
    disponibles = []
    actual      = soluciones[-1]
 
    # Influencia de cada valor (alfa: feromonas; beta: valor)
    alfa = 1.0
    beta = 0.5
   

    # El parámetro beta (peso de los valores) es 0.5 y alfa=1.0
    for i in range(len(valors)):
        if i not in visitados: 
            fer  = math.pow((1.0 + ferom[actual][i]), alfa)
            peso = math.pow(1.0/valors[actual][i], beta) * fer
            disponibles.append(i)
            listaValores.append(peso)

    
    # Se elige aleatoriamente una de los nodos disponibles,
    # teniendo en cuenta su peso relativo.
    valor     = random.random() * sum(listaValores)
    acumulado = 0.0
    i         = -1
    while valor > acumulado:
        i         += 1
        acumulado += listaValores[i]
 
 
    return disponibles[i]
```

JAVA

```
public static int eligeNodo(int valors[][], int ferom[][], List visitados, List soluciones) {
        //Se calcula la tabla de pesos de cada ciudad
        List listaValores = new LinkedList();
        List disponibles = new LinkedList();
        int actual = (int) soluciones.get(-1);

        //Influencia de cada valor (alfa: feromonas; beta: valor)
        double alfa = 1.0;
        double beta = 0.5;
        double fer, peso;

        //El parámetro beta (peso de los valores) es 0.5 y alfa=1.0
        for (int i = 0; i <= valors.length; i++) {
            if (noEnVector(i, visitados)) {
                fer = Math.pow((1.0 + ferom[actual][i]), alfa);
                peso = Math.pow((1.0 / valors[actual][i]), beta) * fer;
                disponibles.add(i);
                listaValores.add(peso);
            }
        }

        //Se elige aleatoriamente una de los nodos disponibles,
        //teniendo en cuenta su peso relativo.
        double valor = (int) Math.random() * sum(listaValores);
        double acumulado = 0.0;
        int i = -1;
        while (valor > acumulado) {
            i += 1;
            acumulado += (int) listaValores.get(i);
        }

        return (int) disponibles.get(i);
    }
```

Comment: Edita tu pregunta añadiendo también los erres que te muestra, que hace el método que quieres convertir y si es posible un ejemplo de entrada de datos y los resultados que debería retornar el método. ;)

Comment: No conozco *Java*. Quizás te interese utilizar [Jython](https://www.jython.org/) en lugar de reescribir el código en *java*.

Comment: Supongo que te da error en `soluciones.get(-1)` por estar fuera de rango. Mejor usa `soluciones.getLast()` para obtener el último elemento de una `LinkedList`. Si no es ése el error, añádelo a la pregunta para tener alguna pista de qué te pasa.

Answer (score 1):

Una traducción uno a uno sería:

```
public static int eligeNodo(int valors[][], int ferom[][], List<Integer> visitados, List<Integer> soluciones) {
    //Se calcula la tabla de pesos de cada ciudad
    List<Double> listaValores = new LinkedList<>();
    List<Integer> disponibles = new LinkedList<>();
    int actual = soluciones.get(soluciones.size()-1);

    //Influencia de cada valor (alfa: feromonas; beta: valor)
    double alfa = 1.0;
    double beta = 0.5;
    double fer, peso;

    //El parámetro beta (peso de los valores) es 0.5 y alfa=1.0
    for (int i = 0; i <= valors.length; i++) {
        if (!visitados.contains(i)) {
            fer = Math.pow((1.0 + ferom[actual][i]), alfa);
            peso = Math.pow((1.0 / valors[actual][i]), beta) * fer;
            disponibles.add(i);
            listaValores.add(peso);
        }
    }

    //Se elige aleatoriamente una de los nodos disponibles,
    //teniendo en cuenta su peso relativo.
    int suma=listaValores.stream().mapToInt(Integer::intValue).sum();
    double valor = (int) Math.random() * suma;
    double acumulado = 0.0;
    int i = -1;
    while (valor > acumulado) {
        i += 1;
        acumulado += listaValores.get(i).intValue();
    }

    return -1 ==i? -1 : disponibles.get(i);
}
```

y para ello cabe hacer notar que en la traducción que intentaste:

- `soluciones.get(-1)` lo tomaría como un índice negativo por raro que parezca.
- `noEnVector(i, visitados)` no hay un método para verificar la "no existencia", así que usamos lógica negada en ese punto mediante `!list.contains(aBuscar)`.
- no hay funciones de suma cargadas por defecto que manejen todas las colecciones por defecto, deberemos de usar las funciones que provea el api de colecciones de java.

El código traducido es funcional, pero pareciera como si se hubiera hecho hace unos 6 años, así que traducido a algo más moderno quedaría así:

```
public class Main {

    //Influencia de cada valor (alfa: feromonas; beta: valor)
    static final double ALFA = 1.0;
    static final double BETA = 0.5;
    public static int eligeNodo(int valors[][], int ferom[][], List<Integer> visitados, List<Integer> soluciones) {
        //Se calcula la tabla de pesos de cada ciudad
        int actual = soluciones.get(soluciones.size() - 1);
        List<Double> listaValores = new LinkedList<>();
        List<Integer> disponibles = new LinkedList<>();

        actualizaInfluencia(valors, ferom[actual], visitados, actual, listaValores, disponibles);


        int indiceNodoSeleccionado = eligealeatoriamenteNodoDisponible(listaValores);


        return -1 == indiceNodoSeleccionado ? -1 : disponibles.get(indiceNodoSeleccionado);
    }

    private static int eligealeatoriamenteNodoDisponible(Collection<Double> listaValores) {
        //Se elige aleatoriamente una de los nodos disponibles,
        //teniendo en cuenta su peso relativo.
        double suma = listaValores.stream().mapToDouble(Double::intValue).sum();
        double valor = (int) Math.random() * suma;
        double acumulado = 0.0;
        int i = -1;
        Iterator<Double> valoresIterador = listaValores.iterator();
        while (valor > acumulado) {
            if (valoresIterador.hasNext()) {
                acumulado += valoresIterador.next();
                i += 1;
            } else {
                break;
            }
        }
        return i;
    }

    private static void actualizaInfluencia(int[][] valors, int[] ints, List<Integer> visitados, int actual, List<Double> listaValores, List<Integer> disponibles) {
        IntStream.range(0, valors.length)
                .paralel()
                .filter(indice -> !visitados.contains(indice))
                .forEach(index -> {
                    disponibles.add(index);
                    double fer = Math.pow((1.0 + ints[index]), ALFA);
                    listaValores.add(Math.pow((1.0 / valors[actual][index]), BETA) * fer);
                });
    }
}
```

Las ventajas del nuevo código son las siguientes:

- al tener métodos más pequeños es más fácil de mantener, pues se ocultan detalles en métodos
- al estar más delimitados en el ámibto de métodos algunas variables el uso de memoria es mejor, ya que se marcan más frecuentemente los espacios reservados para las variables con el propósito de ser liberados
- el uso de iteradores nos permite navegar en estructuras de datos eliminando algunos indices que a la larga serán fuente de complejidad y fallos
- El código está más desacoplado lo que permite cambiar las estructuras de datos sin afectar la funcionalidad en caso de modificaciones
- el uso del stream API nos permite fácilmente hacer que nuestro código pueda hacer cálculos de manera asíncrona haciéndolo más escalable y eficiente